# Are there any CDN that permits to customize the jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, customization, cdn

we've been using just a few of jquery-ui library in our service, currently the Sortable. The libraries are taken from CDN of google as this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Currently we need to optimize the client side and it seems the customization of jquery-ui is not supported by google, but it would be quite nice to have something of this type

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js?modules=core,widget,mouse,sortable" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Are there any CDN that can provide this kind of functionality you or we should host ourself version of custom library?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably host it yourself--I can't imagine many people will have the specific version of jQueryUI you have, which is one of the benefits of using a CDN (avoiding re-downloading the script).

Comment: Keeping library updated, optimize the library weight and still using CDN, is it a sufficient to make it real (we speak about text files so to keep one or thousands copies does not change much in space)? In any case there are only a few combinations of libraries that can be produced not a factorial N!

Answer (score 2):

It actually does not make much sense using a customized CDN hosted library, at least for a library like jQuery UI which has many customization possibilites.

The purpose of a CDN like the Google CDN is mainly "to make the web faster" (as Google says, *besides having a very good overview which library is used on which homepage, which is another topic*). So if multiple sites all are using the same library from a CDN (**with the same URL**) their browser (or any proxy server) could use an already locally cached library instead of doing a full new download again.

If jQuery UI would be customizable on a CDN chances are very small that another site uses exactly the same configuration like your site, so the advance of speeding up the requests by using cached versions is simply not given.

For example, if you are using

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js?modules=core,widget,mouse,sortable
```

a different set of modules or just another modules order already make a new request.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think a jQuery UI CDN could be very useful!
Maybe some provider will ask you to pay because of bandwidth usage and a single jquery-ui JS could be 20Kb size to more than 70Kb! And I think is not a problem for a CDN like Google to have more versions of jQuery UI (with a clever name, and not parameters in QS), so that the chance of a locally cached library is not null (even if very low)

Comment: For a customizable package like jQueryUI there are dozens of possible combinations for the packages and the chance that any other site is using exact the same combination (for the same version!) is down to zero. For the whole package with everything in it, it of course makes totally sense, but for a customized build it IMO does not make sense at all.